# Find String beween not ending with white space with regex

Tags: regex, string, replace, find

I want to find only "th" in every string but "th" should not be end of string.

Ex.

**Th**is is sentence. ["th" in this should match]

Dashrath is **th**e boy. ["th" in Dashrath should not match] ["th" in the should match]

Anthony is great. ["th" in Anthony should match]

I have tried this,

```
(th\S)
```

But this regex also captures the next capture after "th".

Comment: Try `\b[Tt][Hh]\B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\B` after `th` as `\B` asserts position where `\b` does not match that means match anywhere that is not end of word:

```
(?i)th\B
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wtACFW/1)